# What is the easiest way to implement a self restarting service

Tags: .net, windows-services, service

I have got a windows service written in .NET and I need to be able to implement a self-restarting feature for it.

E.g. service constantly monitors the environment in runs in and once a value of the environmental variable reaches its threashold value the service must restart itself.

What would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Am i the only one thinking that it should not need to be restarted if it is a service? But +1 for the First Failure solution.

Comment: I am a "duct tape" programming, mate. Thus was my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your app monitor the environment variable, and exit when it should, set the service to restart under the recovery tab for the service. You can do this programmatically if you use code to install the service.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Write a Service to start the Service!

Comment: Simple as it sounds, that's the common approach I have seen.

Comment: Heh, reminds me of this - http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~magi/personal/humour/Computer_Folklore/Robin%20Hood%20And%20Friar%20Tuck.html

Comment: You don't need to have 2 services unless you are supporting windows 98 or earlier.